# Laravel 5.4 + WP fatal error on only some routes

Tags: laravel, wordpress, .htaccess, laravel-5

I inherited a Laravel + Wordpress integrated website and had to migrate to a new server. The Wordpress website appears to work fine, and some Laravel routes work, but others do not.

For example, on the website homepage, we get the following error:

```
Call to a member function route() on string

in Kernel.php line 231
at Kernel->gatherRouteMiddleware()
in Kernel.php line 204
at Kernel->terminateMiddleware()
in Kernel.php line 189
at Kernel->terminate()
in index.php line 61
```

On other routes, such as `/donor/` and `/parent/`, the browser simply redirects to the homepage.

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Donor', 'prefix' => 'donor'], function () {

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'application'], function () {
        Route::get('/', [
            'middleware' => ['guest'],
            'as'         => 'donor.initial-application',
            'uses'       => 'InitialApplicationController@showApplication',
        ]);
        Route::post('/', [
            'middleware' => ['guest'],
            'uses'       => 'InitialApplicationController@saveApplication',
        ]);
        Route::get('submitted', [
            'as'         => 'donor.submitted',
            'uses'       => 'InitialApplicationController@applicationSubmitted',
        ]);
        Route::get('rejected', [
            'as'         => 'donor.rejected',
            'uses'       => 'InitialApplicationController@applicationRejected',
        ]);
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.donor'], function () {
        Route::get('/', [
            'as'   => 'donor.dashboard',
            'uses' => 'DashboardController@dashboard',
        ]);
        Route::get('personal', [
            'as'   => 'donor.application.personal',
            'uses' => 'PersonalController@showForm',
        ]);
        
        .... etc ......
```

And on other routes, such as `/account/` or `/admin/` and its children, load without issue.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'namespace' => 'Account', 'prefix' => 'account'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [
        'as'   => 'account',
        'uses' => 'ProfileController@profile',
    ]);
    Route::get('edit', [
        'middleware' => 'profile',
        'as'         => 'account.edit',
        'uses'       => 'ProfileController@edit',
    ]);
    Route::post('edit', [
        'middleware' => 'profile',
        'uses'       => 'ProfileController@update',
    ]);
    Route::get('password', [
        'as'   => 'account.password',
        'uses' => 'PasswordController@edit',
    ]);
    Route::post('password', [
        'uses' => 'PasswordController@update',
    ]);

});
```

I have tried running commands:
`php artisan optimize`
`php artisan cache:clear`
`php artisan route:clear` and did not resolve the issue.

Laravel resides in `/`

Wordpress index and config resides in `/public/`

Wordpress core resides in `/public/wp/`

Another interesting note, at first Wordpress was encountering an endless redirect loop. I was able to fix that by commenting out the following lines in .htaccess:

```
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

I've tried reverting this and it does not seem to affect my problem above.
Not experienced in Laravel so I am unsure what else to try.

Comment: "*had to migrate to a new server*" - how, I mean what did you do, exactly?  Did Apache or PHP versions change?  Did you [set up directory permissions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#configuration)?  Did all `.htaccess` files really get copied over?

Comment: BTW the installation sounds very non-standard, I mean Laravel in `/`, WP in `/public`, and WP core in `/public/wp`?  Where is the docroot?  Are you sure `/public/index.php` is WP's, not Laravel's? Though presumably if it worked before, this is probably not relevant to this problem.

Comment: We went from PHP 7.3 on a runcloud nginx/apache setup to a PHP 7.4 runcloud OLS setup which still allows .htaccess usage.  You are correct about the index.php, it's not a standard Wordpress file and contains quite a bit of stuff relevant to Laravel. However, it is the same on both servers.

Comment: I don't know what a "*runcloud nginx/apache*" set up is (nginx or Apache?), nor what a "*runcloud OLS setup*" is, nor if that change means you switched web servers.  But if you did switch from nginx to Apache or vice versa, you will clearly need to do some extra web server configuration, as both Laravel and WP require URL rewriting.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#pretty-urls, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/deployment#nginx, https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/.